# Replacing a character in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to change `&amp;` to `and` in the my page's meta description.

This is what I tried

```
{% if '&' in dj.name %}
    {{ dj.name.replace('&', 'and') }}
{% else %}
    {{ dj.name }}
{% endif %}
```

This doesn't work. It still shows as `&amp;`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`dj.name.replace('&', 'and')`
You can not invoke method with arguments.You need to write a custom filter.

Official guide is here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Ok, here is my example, say, in an app named 'questions', I want to write a filter `to_and` which replaces '&' to 'and' in a string.

In /project_name/questions/templatetags, create a blank `__init__.py`, and `to_and.py`    which goes like:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def to_and(value):
    return value.replace("&","and")
```

In template , use:

```
{% load to_and %}
```

then you can enjoy:

```
{{ string|to_and }}
```

Note, the directory name `templatetags` and file name `to_and.py` can not be other names.

Comment: I guess it would be better if you write an example filter.

Comment: It would be better if your example address `& » and` replacement. Since it will completely answer OP's question.

Comment: file name and function's name doesn't need to be same, since we can write multiple tags in same file we can name it like `my_templatetags.py` and the only change will be to change load to `{% load my_templatetags %}`.

Answer (score 20):

More useful:

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def replace(value, arg):
    """
    Replacing filter
    Use `{{ "aaa"|replace:"a|b" }}`
    """
    if len(arg.split('|')) != 2:
        return value

    what, to = arg.split('|')
    return value.replace(what, to)
```

Answer (score 6):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#accessing-method-calls) says thus:

> Because Django intentionally limits the amount of logic processing available in the template language, it is not possible to pass arguments to method calls accessed from within templates. Data should be calculated in views, then passed to templates for display.

You will have to edit `dj.name` beforehand.

*Edit:* looks like Pythoner knows a better way: [registering a custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters). Upvote him ;)