# Django Template: remove underscore and capitalize each word

Tags: django, django-template-filters

Is there any filter in Django that can remove underscores and also capitalize each letter of the word OR remove underscores and capitalize the first letter of sentence?

Comment: 1. There's no filter to remove underscores, you need to create one. 2. Filter `{{ string|title }}` could do the each word capitalization, but not for all sentences if your text contains more than one sentence.

Comment: Thanks @ShangWang I will try writing my own filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capitalize your word you could use [`capfirst`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst) template tag:

```
{{ value|capfirst }}
# If value is "django", the output will be "Django".
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/) you can find more built-in tags.

To remove underscore, I think there's no filter that do that, [you could write your own template tag filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) or pre-process the word in your view replacing underscores:

```
word = 'hello_world'
word = word.replace('_', ' ')
```

Comment: I will try writing my own filter

Answer (score 6):

```
@register.filter()
def field_name_to_label(value):
    value = value.replace('_', ' ')
    return value.title()
```

Comment: It worked great thank you.  
This also guided me on how to create a custom filter with arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483003/replacing-a-character-in-django-template
and this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/