# Replace underscore with spaces in Jinja

Tags: html, jinja2

I'm trying to replace underscore with spaces, I tried the solution below:
[Django Template: remove underscore and capitalize each word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885752/django-template-remove-underscore-and-capitalize-each-word)

but it just keep the first word and remove the rest of the string:

example: min_wall_hight

output: min

my code:

```
.
.
.
{% for i in t[1:] %}
<input type="text" name={{i[0]}} value={{i[0]|replace("_"," ")|capitalize}} readonly>
{% endfor %}
.
.
.
```

when I use the filter in this way :{{i[0]|replace("_","-")|capitalize}} or without space just "" it works fine. but when it's space " " it will discard the rest of string
can someone help I'm new jinja