# Using context variables inside text inside template tag in django

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

I want to do something like this in my template.

```
{% include "blogs/blogXYZ.html" %}
```

The XYZ part should be variable. ie how can I pass a context variable to this position. For example if I am reading 1st blog, I should be able to include blog1.html. If I am reading 2nd blog, I should be able to include blog2.html and so on. Is it possible in django?

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483003/replacing-a-character-in-django-template

Answer (score 2):

You can write a [custom tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) to accept variable to build a template name in runtime..

The following approach is leveraging the `string.format` function to build a dynamic template name, it may have some issues when you need to pass more than two variable to format the template name, so you may need amend and customise the following code to fulfil your requirement.

**your_app_dir/templatetags/custom_tags.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template.loader_tags import do_include
from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError, Token


register = template.Library()


@register.tag('xinclude')
def xinclude(parser, token):
    '''
    {% xinclude "blogs/blog{}.html/" "123" %}
    '''
    bits = token.split_contents()
    if len(bits) < 3:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            "%r tag takes at least two argument: the name of the template to "
            "be included, and the variable" % bits[0]
        )
    template = bits[1].format(bits[2])
    # replace with new template
    bits[1] = template
    # remove variable
    bits.pop(2)
    # build a new content with the new template name
    new_content = ' '.join(bits)
    # build a new token,
    new_token = Token(token.token_type, new_content)
    # and pass it to the build-in include tag
    return do_include(parser, new_token)  # <- this is the origin `include` tag
```

Usage in your template:

```
<!-- load your custom tags -->
{% load custom_tags %}

<!-- Include blogs/blog123.html -->
{% xinclude "blogs/blog{}.html" 123 %}

<!-- Include blogs/blog456.html -->
{% xinclude "blogs/blog{}.html" 456 %}
```

Comment: Cant we use "return do_include(parser, template)" after new template name is generated?. Why further processing the bits?

Comment: that's because the `xinclude` parameter is used to generate the template name only, and param is no longer needed when you have built a template name. in other word, `xinclude` is used to dynamically generate a tag: `{% include "blogs/blog123.html" %}`