# How do I add the project title to the project_details url's (slug) on this django project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I've been stuck trying to add the project title to the project_details urls (slug).
The issue is, I would rather achieve this without changing the models.py as this would create complications with the db...

Is there a way to achieve this with just changes to the veiws.py, urls.py and the link tag?

Here is my code, any help is much appreciated...

```
from django.shortcuts import render from django.views.generic import TemplateView from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404 from .models import ProjectPost from django.db.models import Q from django.db.models import F from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class ProjectsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'projects.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_post = ProjectPost.objects.order_by('-created_at')

        paginator = Paginator(project_post, 6)  # Display 6 posts per page
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context['page_obj'] = page_obj
        return context


class ProjectDetailsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_id = self.kwargs.get('project_id')
        project = get_object_or_404(ProjectPost, pk=project_id)

        context['project'] = project
        return context
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProjectsView, ProjectDetailsView



urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', ProjectsView.as_view(), name='projects'),
    path('project_details/<int:project_id>/', ProjectDetailsView.as_view(), name='project_details'),
]
```

For safe measure here is the models however I would like to achieve adding the title without adding a slug field if possible

```
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.utils import timezone

User = get_user_model()

def get_default_author():
    if User.objects.exists():
        return f"{User.objects.first().first_name} {User.objects.first().last_name}"
    return 'Default Author'

def get_default_date():
    return timezone.now()

class ProjectPost(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=get_default_author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=get_default_date)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='project_pictures/')
    description = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

example code (this didn't work got 404 error)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import ProjectPost
from django.db.models import Q
from django.db.models import F
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

class ProjectsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'projects.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_post = ProjectPost.objects.order_by('-created_at')

        paginator = Paginator(project_post, 6)  # Display 6 posts per page
        page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

        context['page_obj'] = page_obj
        return context


class ProjectDetailsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        project_id = self.kwargs.get('project_id')
        project = get_object_or_404(ProjectPost, pk=project_id)

        context['project'] = project
        context['project_slug'] = project.title.replace(" ", "-")  # Add project slug to the context

        return context




from django.urls import path
from .views import ProjectsView, ProjectDetailsView

urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', ProjectsView.as_view(), name='projects'),
    path('project_details/<int:project_id>/<slug:project_slug>/', ProjectDetailsView.as_view(), name='project_details'),
]


<a href="{% url 'project_details' project.id project.title.replace(' ', '-') %}">Project Details</a>
```

the error returned is as follows:

```
    <a href="{% url 'project_details' project.id project.title.replace(' ', '-') %}" class="card-blog-link" style="text-decoration: none;">
```

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /projects/

Could not parse the remainder: '(' ',' from 'project.title.replace(' ','
Django Version:     3.2.19
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    

Could not parse the remainder: '(' ',' from 'project.title.replace(' ','
```

Comment: can you give an example how it should  lool like?

Comment: yep I've added an example that I tried previously.

Comment: it looks ok. what is the rendered href? can you show the error trace?

Comment: I've added the error and href indicating the issue is with the href tag

Comment: replace can not be used in that way. just use project_slug that you add to context in the view.

Answer (score 0):

you can generate the slug in the model:

```
class ProjectPost(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=get_default_author)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=get_default_date)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='project_pictures/')
    description = models.TextField()
    content = RichTextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def title_slug():
        return self.title.replace(" ", "-")
```

you can access the slug in the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'project_details' project.id project.title_slug %}">Project Details</a>
```

see also this if you want to do it in the template [Replacing a character in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483003/replacing-a-character-in-django-template)