# Python Django Json Data Serialization

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I've got an issue where I want to pass the whole data set of the profile page using data serialization as below, however the issue is that I get the output data with single quotes instead of double and I cannot parse it later on:

View:

```
def profile_page(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = WeightLogForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        weight_log = form.save(commit=False)
        weight_log.profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        weight_log.save()
        return redirect('profile')
else:
    form = WeightLogForm()

user_weight_log = WeightRecord.objects.filter(profile__user=request.user).order_by('-entry_date')

paginator = Paginator(user_weight_log, 10)

page = request.GET.get('page')

try:
    user_weight_log = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    user_weight_log = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    user_weight_log = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

serialized_data = [{'weight': str(record.weight), 'entry_date': record.entry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} for record in
                   user_weight_log]

return render(request, 'profile.html', {
    'user_weight_log': user_weight_log,
    'form': form,
    'weight_data': serialized_data
})
```

Html Template:

```
<div id="weight-data" data-weight-data="{{ weight_data|safe }}"></div>
```

Data output:

> [{'weight': '122.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-28'}, {'weight': '123.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-18'}, {'weight': '44.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-15'}, {'weight': '85.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-06'}, {'weight': '11.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-06'}, {'weight': '12.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-05'}, {'weight': '17.00', 'entry_date': '2023-09-05'}, {'weight': '44.00', 'entry_date': '2023-08-08'}, {'weight': '17.00', 'entry_date': '2023-06-08'}, {'weight': '33.00', 'entry_date': '2023-06-07'}]

Javascript:

```
var weightDataElement = document.getElementById('weight-data');
var weightDataJSON = weightDataElement.getAttribute('data-weight-data');
var weightData = JSON.parse(weightDataJSON);
```

The error I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: The output is not JSON: json requires double quotes for the keys...

Comment: I know it requires double quotes however I don't know how to get the data with double quotes as my code (serialized_data = [{'weight': str(record.weight), 'entry_date': record.entry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} for record in
                   user_weight_log]) yields me single quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're getting is the python representation of the dictionary. As others pointed out, this is not JSON yet.

To output the data as JSON, the easiest way to do so is to use python's `json` package and the function `dumps` which outputs the inputted data as a json string.

```py
from json import dumps

# ...

# use dumps to serialize the data to json format
serialized_data = dumps([{'weight': str(record.weight), 'entry_date': record.entry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} for record in
                   user_weight_log])

return render(request, 'profile.html', {
    'user_weight_log': user_weight_log,
    'form': form,
    'weight_data': serialized_data
})
```

Alternatively, for your specific case, there's also a [template filter provided by django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-json_script) which outputs any data as json, embedded within a `<script type="application/json">` element. You could use this in your case within the template like

```html
{{ weight_data|json_script:"weight-data" }}
```

Comment: while `dumps` function didn't get me what I've wanted `{{ weight_data|json_script:"weight-data" }}` solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var weightDataElement = document.getElementById('weight-data');
console.log(weightDataElement);
var weightDataJSON = weightDataElement.getAttribute('data-weight-data');
console.log(weightDataJSON);
var weightData = JSON.parse(weightDataJSON);
console.log(weightData);
```

```html
<div id="weight-data" data-weight-data="[{&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;122.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-28&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;123.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-18&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;44.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-15&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;85.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-06&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;11.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-06&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;12.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-05&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;17.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-09-05&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;44.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-08-08&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;17.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-06-08&quot;}, {&quot;weight&quot;: &quot;33.00&quot;, &quot;entry_date&quot;: &quot;2023-06-07&quot;}]"></div>
```

JSON requires double quotes

Comment: how can I get double quotes? My current view part gets me single quotes:

serialized_data = [{'weight': str(record.weight), 'entry_date': record.entry_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} for record in user_weight_log]

Comment: Assuming the `weight_data|safe` is already a string you could replace all `'` for `&quot;` which is what I use in my snippet

Comment: Check this if you want to create a [tag to do the replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21483185/5640517) (and any other transformations)